# anyone could guess you write/wrote/had written it

Tags: tense, present-tense, conditionals

In a classroom, one student (A) to another (B):

A: I'm surprised! How did you know I wrote it on the board? (The writing is still there on the board)

B: It's pretty simple. Looking at the handwriting, anyone could guess you write/wrote/had written it. (Guessing about present)

Which of the verb tenses "write", "wrote" and "had written" is (are) correct?

Comment: The present tense is definitely wrong. I would say "Anyone could guess that you had written it".

Comment: Thank you :). In the same context, can I also say: "Anyone could've guessed that you wrote it"? (Guessing about the past)

Comment: "Could have guessed" is about guessing _in_ the past, not _about_ it.